# How to bind "Ctrl-Alt-b" as the prefix of tmux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, tmux

Tmux uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> as its prefix, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> conflict with Emacs.

I want to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to tmux's prefix. I guess it may be `C-M-b` but didn't work...

Comment: `C-M-b` works here with tmux 1.6, rxvt-unicode terminal.

Comment: As @Thor has implied, you should post your terminal emulator and tmux version, and possibly even your window manager.

Comment: I don't know why but... M-C-b works... Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`M-C-b` works for me. Outside `tmux`, check what sequence of characters is sent upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-b</kbd>. If it's Esc, ^B (0x1b, 0x2), then that should work.

Comment: Then, how to check what sequences of characters are sent?? Tried your `{ stty raw min 1 time 20 -echo; dd count=1 2> /dev/null | od -vAn -tx1; stty sane; }`; all I get as result is `3c` when I press `C-<` (Ctrl+LessThan). I do want to bind `C-<` as tmux prefix.