# How can I bind Ctrl-Alt-[0-9] in Tmux?

Tags: tmux

I am able to bind Ctrl-Alt-[a-z] using M-C-a, M-C-b etc.

However, when I attempt to bind Ctrl-Alt and a number key I get:

```
.tmux.conf: 45: unknown key: M-C-0
```

Any idea why? I'm running tmux ver 1.7

Related: [How to bind "Ctrl-Alt-b" as the prefix of tmux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48264/how-to-bind-ctrl-alt-b-to-the-prefix-of-tmux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `tmux` does not expect a <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

In `key_string_lookup_string`, it strips off the modifiers, and then (because you have the <kbd>control</kbd> modifier) tries to convert it from something like `^A` (see [source code](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/key-string.c#L203)).  But ASCII digits range from 48 to 57, and you can see from the code that `tmux` will not accept a digit, returning [**`KEYC_UNKNOWN`**](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/key-string.c#L214) (a failure):

```
/* Convert the standard control keys. */
if (key < KEYC_BASE && (modifiers & KEYC_CTRL) && !strchr(other, key)) {
    if (key >= 97 && key <= 122)
        key -= 96;
    else if (key >= 64 && key <= 95)
        key -= 64;
    else if (key == 32)
        key = 0;
    else if (key == 63)
        key = KEYC_BSPACE;
    else
        return (KEYC_UNKNOWN);
    modifiers &= ~KEYC_CTRL;
}
```