# tmux select window with Alt<number>

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

In tmux to select a window, the default behavior is `C-b <number>`.
I would like to avoid the prefix by using alt+ for a faster selecting.

I did it for the next and previous window, and it works:

```
 bind -n M-n select-window -n
 bind -n M-p select-window -p
```

For the selection by id, I did the same, but it does not work:

```
bind -n M-0 select-window -t 0
bind -n M-1 select-window -t 1
bind -n M-2 select-window -t 2
bind -n M-3 select-window -t 3
bind -n M-4 select-window -t 4
bind -n M-5 select-window -t 5
bind -n M-6 select-window -t 6
bind -n M-7 select-window -t 7
bind -n M-8 select-window -t 8
bind -n M-9 select-window -t 9
```

Is there an easy way to make it working?

Comment: I find tmux to be flummoxing.

Comment: Your configuration works for me where `Alt+key` combinations usually work. For example they work in `gnome-terminal`, but in `xterm` not. So in `xterm` I have to use `Esc, key` sequence instead, not only in `tmux`, but for example in `mc` too. I would say, your `tmux` configuration is fine, the host terminal messes things up.

Comment: For me it does not work in `gnome-terminal` neither in `xterm`. I have to use `Esc, key` to make it works for about the half of the keys.

Comment: @Phantom It works for me in MobaXterm.

Comment: The bindings work for me in Tmux 2.6 in Konsole 17.12.3.

Comment: The bindings work on Putty + Tmux

Answer (score 1):

You can create shortcuts to cycle through windows using the `bind-key` command.

So, to select windows using `Alt+<number>`, you can do:

```
bind-key -n M-1 selectw -t 1
bind-key -n M-2 selectw -t 2
bind-key -n M-3 selectw -t 3
(...)
```

Comment: worked for me (using kitty on macos)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102170/how-can-i-bind-ctrl-alt-0-9-in-tmux) tmux does not support numeric characters to keybinding.

Because I'm using tmux with [iTerm](https://iterm2.com/) I'd a workaround:

- On iTerm -> preferences -> Keys -> Key binding: I did bind the key+number to a specific char, e.g.: `C-0 ->`  ; `C-1 ->`  ; etc
- on .tmux.conf I do use that char: `bind·-n··…`

To other terminal clients, I guess there is an option to map the keys in the same way, so it is just a matter to find how to map the keys.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that tmux does not allow numeric characters for keybinding. But from what I saw, iTerm is only for Mac, so it won't be useful as I'm under Linux

Comment: I see, under Linux, you have even more options… To use the same workaround you can use [konsole](https://kde.org/download/) it does have the remap functionality in the same way as iterm… I did a VM to try it and it works, look: https://imgur.com/gallery/0u1bnkP